# Gimp - How to fade out or into a Gaussian blur

Tags: gimp

I'm running Gimp 2.10.34

I know how to use Gaussian blur on images, but is there a non-destructive way to fade out or into a Gaussian blur, similar to using the gradient tool over a white layer mask?

I want the bottom of my image to remain sharp, and as you begin to look up, it shows more and more of the Gaussian blur.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use GIMP's Focus Blur filter. It's not non-destructive, but you can create a layer from visible, and apply it to that layer, leaving your original layers unchanged.

Set it up like this.

[image]Click to view larger

Comment: Feels like this tool was built for this very question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you just stack a "sharp" version and "blurred" version, and add a layer mask with a gradient to unmask progressively the bottom picture:

[image]

Comment: Nice and Simple - Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No need to change what's upvoted or accepted, but take some information:

Blending a sharp layer with its blurred copy with a gradient layer mask causes the sharp version gradually to fade behind the blurred version. In the transition zone the sharp version can still be seen as sharp behind the blurred version.

Someone may actually want totally different transition: A gradually growing blur radius like this:

[image]

When the blur becomes visible at certain distance from the image center, there's absolutely no ghost of the sharp version visible.

This effect is unfortunately destructive. As a workaround, keep a non-blurred backup copy of the original layer.

The effect is Lens Blur in G'MIC filter collection:

[image]

It's available for free to GIMP, Photoshop and Paint.NET. To Krita it's installed as a default.

To stay in truth GIMP and Photoshop both have working native Lens Blur effects. In Photoshop it can be controlled with layer mask and in GIMP it can be controlled with another layer. G'MIC version is much more handy if its controls are flexible enough for the intended purpose. GIMP has also "Variable Blur" which at first sight looks the same as GIMP's lens blur, but the programmers of the effects may somewhere reveal the difference. I have not seen it.

The effect is originally intended to simulate the blurring which happens in big cameras with wide lens aperture - only items which are in the relative shallow well focused distance range are imaged as sharp. Small format cameras do not have this property. Many photographers see it harmful, because automatically blurred background would effectively make the foreground target more present.

As a winding down here's another example of using the same filter:

[image]

Comment: very nice lesson!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is no longer about fading a Gaussian blur:

Gimp also has the [Variable blur](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-filter-variable-blur.html) with which you can define a blur mask that tells how much the area should be blurred:

[image]